# "Programs running in/on machine”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition should be used in the following sentence?

> All of my programs are running **in/on** a 16-core machine.

Google shows both options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Programs run *on*, and not *in*, a computer or machine.

> - I can run Windows *on* my mac using Boot Camp.
> - Memory-intensive applications run *on* my multicore monster of a machine like  a dream.

Consider these sentences, though:

> - I run all my programs *in* Windows *on* my mac.
> - Office 2004 won't run *in* Snow Leopard, will it?

Generally, software to hardware takes *on*, while software to software takes *in*.

Comment: +1 Better defined than my answer.

Comment: I think this comes from the metaphor whereby hardware forms a "platform" for software, whereas an OS creates an "environment".

Comment: @Knechtel: Excellent! *Environment* came into my head for software, but I couldn't think of the equivalent metaphor for hardware, so I simply decided to leave that out. Great point!

Comment: I'm not so sure about the on/in thing; _Most games don't work on Linux_ sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Javier: I agree that both _on_ and _in_ sound fine when talking about OSes.

Comment: @Karl An OS is both a platform and an environment. Lots of technical stuff behind that, but that's the way it is.

Comment: Sometimes even [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+Windows%2Cunder+Windows%2Cin+Windows%2Cwithin+Windows&year_start=1985&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) can be useful, also see these two [1](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runs+on+Windows%2C+runs+in+Windows%2C+runs+under+Windows%2C+runs+within+Windows&year_start=1985&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), [2](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runs+under+Linux%2Cruns+on+Linux%2Cruns+in+Linux%2Cruns+within+Linux&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 6):

**On**. Programs running *on* a computer is more common (though both are used), and sounds more natural to my ear.  The ratio seems to be about 4:1 in favor of *on*, according to Google, and even greater in favor of *on*, according to [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=running%20in%20the%20computer,running%20on%20the%20computer&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score -1):

Actually my first reaction is that of *on* as opposed to *in*. However taking this into a more general purpose arena.

Machines (both software and hardware) are models of abstract processes or functions. A simple machine encodes a simple function (look at a broom for example). Where are computer enocdes many complex functions.

So looking at it from this perspective, would the execution of these processes (programs) not be embodied within the model as opposed to on the model?

Therefore I must say that both are equally valid unless deeper specificity is required.

Comment: This does not make sense to me at all.  What do you mean by “models of abstract processes”?  Machines and processes are different things.  Moreover, usually a machine is a machine and not a model of anything, unless you are talking about computational models in theoretical computer science such as Turing machines.

Comment: I am. A machine imo is just a substrate or surface upon which the a computational model may be executed. I can see how you say machines and processes are different. However the purpose of any machine is execute a mathematical function and as such really is the approximation to a process.

Comment: @PreetSangha Your comment gets a +1 for the elucidation, without which the answer cannot be convincing.

Comment: -1 This is largely irrelevant (for language and usage) and mostly overgeneralized. Also, "machines are models" is such narrow view, that from linguistic aspect you can call it outright false. Then, machines do not "encode" a function, nor does using a metaphor such as "surface or substrate" help with clarifying the choice of propositions.

Comment: How can ' is such narrow view, that from linguistic aspect you can call it outright false' be considered anything but a gross oversimplification? Ho hum